# Add Web Api project to existing project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a project that based on columns from a database tables as to present a dashboard.

I've been told to create a Web Api project (added to a windows form project) to obtain the columns data and work it to present the charts.

My windows form project is project1 and the web api is project2.

The idea is when I click a form button, I'll present a html file with the charts. My line of thought is when I press the button project2 will start, with the data already collected in project1, to present a dashboard.

If I'm thinking correctly, my questions are:

1. How can I call the web api when clicking a button
2. How can I pass the information already collected to project2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be you not explaining something right or I don't understand something.

Looks like you adding a Web Api project as part of the solution. Looks like you have some data at Windows application, which then being posted via Web Api to database. If this is correct then:

Web Api is .NET web-centric framework for REST, in which HTTP stack is at the center. In REST you have stateless application running on the web server and you making calls to it. The beauty of REST is that the client can be practically anything - any device, any application, another REST service - anything!

**The answer:**
So, your Windows App can make a call to your REST layer and post data. In your Windows app you will need to reference `System.Net.Http` to use `HttpClient` class. Using this namespace you can compile Http messages and make Http Requests and receive Http Responses.

I think, this is exactly what happening in your solution. Please let me know it it is not what I think.

Comment: when you say "being posted via Web Api to database" you mean insert into database?

Comment: In Web Api you have controllers. When an Http request is routed to your controller and action [method], you can do there whatever you want, and insert into database as well.

Comment: ok, i understand. i have another question
how can i, if possible, access a Properties.Resource from project1 in project2. this is because the data i need to use is in a resource (json). i have been looking and the info i found says that i have to reference a project in the other one, but i can't understand which one will be reference to

Comment: My friend, you can reference, because in the end, web api project is compiled into .dll. But this is NOT what you want to do. If you have a resource that both of your projects use, you need to separate those resources into third assembly and reference that assembly from both projects, if both using same resources. You should never have a situation in which you have references between Web Api and Windows projects.